# Windows drive shows all icons with a "X" tagged!

Tags: windows-7, xubuntu

[image] This is what I'm seeing. Any help?

Comment: Do you have Windows Bitlocker or some other kind of drive encryption program installed?

Comment: Nope.Don't have that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you don't have the necessary permissions to write to the files on the Windows drive. [Ubuntu has a wiki on file permissions.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) However, there is a great program called `pysdm` that makes changing the file permissions for drives quick and easy. It is avalible through the Ubuntu repositories, and therefore can be installed through `sudo apt-get installed pysdm`. A screenshot:

[image]

More information can be found on the project's homepage [here](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/). Hope that helps!